Creating ReplicaSet
I have tried to create a replicaset and got the error
error: error validating "mymavenreplica.yml": error validating data: failed to download openapi: Get "https://192.168.49.2:8443/openapi/v2?timeout=32s": dial tcp 192.168.49.2:8443: connect: no route to host; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
apiVersion : v1
kind : ReplicaSet
metadata :
name : mymavenreplica
spec :
replicas : 3
selector :
template :
metadata :
name : mymavenpod
spec:
containers :
- name : maven
image : maven:4.0.0-alpha-13
